# Sending JSON with array elements inside with axios.post

Tags: json, ruby, vue.js, axios

Inside of a `.vue` file I have this method that ends with an `axios.post` call to a WebService URL attended in Ruby:

```
send_firma: function () {
                                        
    var person1 = {
        "identification": "30633685P",
        "name": "Leon Tolstoi",
        "email": "Leon.tolstoi@gmail.com"
    };
    
    var person2 = {
        "identification": "XCF762yh",
        "name": "Alex White",
        "email": "Alex.white@gmail.com"
    };

    var person_list = [];
    person_list[0] = person1;
    person_list[1] = person2;

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("api_key", "90f4b51b5ac5");
    formData.append("signing_parties", person_list);
                
    var url = 'http://someplace.com:8090/someWS';

    var options = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } };
    
    axios.post(url, formData, options)
        .catch(e => {
            console.log("Send message failed!. " + e)               
    })
}
```

As logs on the other side show, it seems that the problem is that I am not able to send the `person_list` array properly. Look at that [object Object]:

"signing_parties"=>"[object Object]",

Could somebody help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean by logs on the `other side`? How are you logging the formData? Do you have to use formData? Have you checked the result of the `.then` block? If you did, what was the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can send it as json string and in the backend load it as json:

```js
formdata = new FormData()
formData.append("signing_parties", JSON.stringify(person_list))

axios.post(url, formData, options)
    .catch(e => {
        console.log("Send message failed!. " + e)               
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but in that case in the logs I see full escape bars: "signing_parties"=>"[{\"identification\":\"30633685P\",\"name\":\"Leon Tolstoi\",\"email\":\"Leon.tolstoi@gmail.com\"},{\"identification\":\"XCF762yh\",\"name\":\"Alex White\",\"email\":\"Alex.white@gmail.com\"}]"}

Comment: can you make an example sandbox or pen?

Comment: or try adding `var options = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the content type

```js
var options = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
```

Since it's an array you are appending to formData, try to replace this

```js
formData.append("signing_parties", person_list);
```

with this

```js
person_list.forEach((person, index) => {
  formData.append('signing_parties' + '[' + index + ']', person)
})
```

Comment: Sorry, it didnt help

Comment: I have edited it. Again, leave the content type as `multipart/form-data`

Comment: Thank for the effort, but log shows: "signing_parties"=>{"0"=>"[object Object]"}  this is a headache

Comment: Hi, @JLLMNCHR do you need to send it as a formData. Can you not send the data directly as an array of objects?